# Overcome repeatable animation jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple script which slides displayed `div` out of the page through the left border and slides another one in from the right border. There are 3 available states (read classes) for those divs - `.page_container` - displayed on the page, `.page_container_hidden` with `display: none`, `margin-left: 100%` and `.page_container_sliding` with `display: block`, `margin-left: 100%`. After animation is done, I change class of a slided out div to become hidden and making required `div` prepared to slide before triggering an animation on it. My problem is that after second animation is done and a div's class is set to the appropriate to be displayed on page (`.page_container`), script thinks that it is a div which needs to be removed and slides it out. I tried to `$().removeClass().addClass()`, but somehow only `addClass()` works which results in `class='one_class another_class'`. How to overcome this issue? Maybe there is a better way to switch displayed divs on the page?

Please see the snippet here: https://jsfiddle.net/d1o0hxr7/5/

Example HTML:

```
<div id="first_page_container" class="page_container">
<h3>
placeholder
</h3>
</div>
<div id="second_page_container" class="page_container_hidden">
<h3>
placeholder
</h3>
</div>
<div id="third_page_container" class="page_container_hidden">
<h3>
placeholder
</h3>
</div>

<button class="page_switcher" name="first">
1
</button>
<button class="page_switcher" name="second">
2
</button>
<button class="page_switcher" name="third">
3
</button>
```

Example CSS:

```
.page_container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}

.page_container_hidden {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    margin-left: 100%;
}

.page_container_sliding {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 100%;
}
```

Example JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.page_switcher', function () {

    var page_container = $('.page_container:visible')
    var page_container_number = $(this).attr('name')
    var container_id = '#' + page_container_number + '_page_container'

    $(page_container).animate({left : '-=100%'}, 500, function () {
        $(page_container).removeClass('page_container').addClass('page_container_hidden')
        $(container_id).removeClass('page_container_hidden').addClass('page_container_sliding')
        $(container_id).animate({left: '-=100%'}, 500)
        $(container_id).removeClass('page_container_sliding').addClass('page_container')
    })
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe move the final removeClass().addClass() into the complete function of the nested animate().

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Nope, I tested it and it ain't working either.